# Simple parameter function doesn’t work as intended

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

So I got a simple script which allows me to show/hide my hamburger navigation.

```
document.getElementById("hamburger_menu").addEventListener("click", show);

    function show() {
        document.getElementById("navigation").classList.toggle("show");
    }
```

This script works perfectly fine. As I want to reuse the script to show my searchbar I decided to use parameters in my script. To make this happen I made my script like this:

```
    function show(target) {
        document.getElementById(target).classList.toggle("show");
    }

document.getElementById("hamburger_menu").addEventListener("click", show("navigation"));
```

But for some weird reason this script is completely broken. Any advice here?

Comment: You are calling the function and setting what it returns to the click handler `addEventListener("click", function() { show("navigation") });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handler for your click event can't be a function call, it needs to be an actual function.
You could do an anonymous function like

```
document.getElementById("hamburger_menu").addEventListener('click', () => show("navigation"));
```

instead.